# Using IPC as a multithread substitute?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was wondering if you could theoretically utilise more than one core of of a processor to complete tasks quicker by using inter process communication instead of multithreading.

Say for instance a game engine. You have one executable processing ai and physics, then another handling the sound and rendering.

Maybe there could be shared memory that the physics and ai results get written to, that the renderer then could use to output the graphics.

What do you think? Ridiculous idea or feasible?

Thank you for your time.

Edit: the engine does not exist, it's just an example. Basically I'm asking if two or more programs can work  together if any tasks can be parallelized.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically I'm asking if two or more programs can work together if any tasks can be parallelized.

Yes, the idea isn't flawed in principle.

That being said, creating a thread and creating a process vary on different OSes in terms of overhead; Windows processes are very expensive to create, while Linux ones are pretty much free.

One advantage of separating the processes is that when one of them crashes, the others aren't impacted and it can be restarted. You can also more easily push the calculations to another machine across the network. However, synchronizing threads will probably be easier and more performant in most cases.

Comment: Multithreading can be difficult to implement so I thought you could make a single threaded exe that uses another's output. This is why I used a game engine as the example. Game loops can't easily be parallelized as each stage depends on the previous one. Like input-ai-physics-etc-render. Plus the speed of the loop will determine the time step in the physics etc. I was thinking one core could update the physics as fast as it can, then the render loop could just render whatever is sitting in the results of the shared memory from the physics at that time, again as fast as it can.

Comment: Threads, not processes, are assigned to processor cores.  So whether the "physics thread" and the "render thread" are in the same process or not is irrelevant in terms of performance.

Comment: Also, the thread synchronization between the physics thread and the render thread is the same whether they are in the same or different processes --- e.g. the render thread needs to wait until there is some data to render, what difference does it make whether the data is put into some shared memory from another process, or into some memory in the same process?